# Jquery function css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want know if this script is bad, not working for me :

```
jQuery(".template_content_img").css({
    width: "50%",
    height: "150px",
    //// Here gives me error 
    font-size: "12px",
    margin-bottom: "23px",
});
```

I don´t know if the problem it´s is "width:200px" or "width","150px"

These are my dudes, by another side I see also many people use animate for this and no use css but why do you suppose the animate create effect and transformation of divs and by this only I need change somethings but it's not working.

Regards !!!

Comment: See the documentation.

Comment: Did you ever try  `.css({'width':50%, 'height':150px})` ?

Comment: @PSL - good but `50%` or `150px` is string so must be in quotes or apostrofs

Comment: @Shaddow oh yeah.. i din't notice... :)

Comment: @user2501504 Put the property keys in quotes. `"font-size"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [jQuery .css](http://api.jquery.com/css) documentation

```
jQuery(".template_content_img").css({
    "width": "50%",
    "height": "150px"
});

jQuery(".template_img").css({
    "width": "70%",
    "height": "100px"
});
```

**EDIT**: If you want add `font-size` or `margin-bottom`, just use classic CSS attributes/values

```
jQuery(".template_content_img").css({
    "width": "50%",
    "height": "150px"
    "font-size": "12px",
    "margin-bottom": "23px",
});
```

Comment: And one question how i can put this or use if i want put also for example othe things as fot-size , font-weight , margin-bottom , etc , thank´s for the help

Comment: just use classic CSS attributes/values

Answer (score 1):

For multi-word CSS attributes, either use quotes:

```
"font-size": "12px",
```

or camelCase:

```
fontSize: "12px",
```

The object has to be a valid Javascript object literal, and delimiters like `-` are not allowed in unquoted property names.

Comment: +1 for having both options and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the css properties as a javascript Object using literals:

```
$('.class').css({
   width : '50%',
   height : '150px'
});
```

Comment: -1 irrelevant to the question

Comment: Because it completely fails to address the cause of the error.